# Why does my code return the scripth path instead of the absolute file path?

Tags: python, for-loop, path, os.walk

I´m facing a little problem in Python that's driving me crazy. My code consists of a very simple `os.walk()` function which is supposed to find all the files and their paths within a test folder (this test folder consists of various sub folders).

```
import os

src=r"C:\Users\j2the\Documents\Test3"

for dirpath,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(src):
    for e in filenames:
        print(e)
        print(os.path.abspath(e))
```

Now, when I run the code, it does print the correct file name. However, even though I used the `os.path.abspath()` statement, the file path returned is always the script path of my pycharm project, that is to say `"C:\Users\j2the\PycharmProjects\..."`.

So why does Python return the script path and not the absolute path of the file, which should be something like `"C:\Users\j2the\Documents\Test3\..."`?

Note: My Pycharm configurations cannot be the problem, since I ran the same code on IDLE and it still returned the script path

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `e` is just a string of a filename. It doesn't contain any information on where it is. If we combine that with [the documentation of `abspath`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath):

> Return a normalized absolutized version of the pathname path. On most platforms, this is equivalent to calling the function normpath() as follows: normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path)).

Thus `path` equals `e`, which is just a filename, say `my_file.txt`. and `os.getcwd()` is the path where the script is run from.

Looking at [the documentation for `os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk), we can see:

> **dirpath is a string, the path to the directory.** dirnames is a list of the names of the subdirectories in dirpath (excluding '.' and '..'). filenames is a list of the names of the non-directory files in dirpath. Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. **To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name).**

* *My emphasis*

Now we can combine these two pieces of knowledge and produce this:

```
import os

src=r"C:\Users\j2the\Documents\Test3"

for dirpath,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(src):
    for e in filenames:
        print(e)
        print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, e)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was an absolutely wonderful and perfect answer! :)